# Fanchart Color Scale

Tags: r, plot, colors, axis-labels

I have the following predictions which I obtained from `library(vars)`. Lets call this `vecm.pred`

```
$price
     fcst    lower    upper        CI
[1,] 4956.787 4864.032 5049.543  92.75548
[2,] 4948.936 4844.545 5053.327 104.39064
[3,] 5089.440 4979.941 5198.939 109.49891
[4,] 5076.999 4939.429 5214.569 137.56992
[5,] 5000.012 4854.955 5145.068 145.05669
[6,] 5072.107 4910.435 5233.780 161.67272

$people
     fcst    lower    upper       CI
[1,] 2529.799 2417.699 2641.899 112.1000
[2,] 2498.627 2269.438 2727.817 229.1893
[3,] 2410.037 2116.672 2703.402 293.3648
[4,] 2418.197 2094.965 2741.429 323.2320
[5,] 2371.373 2028.816 2713.929 342.5561
[6,] 2289.163 1941.386 2636.939 347.7764
```

I am trying to use `fanchart` to show my forecasts below:

```
fanchart(vecm.pred, ylab = c("Price (€)","Volume"), main = c("Price","People"))
```

But I cannot get past the following issues:

1) How do I change the colors from the default grey scale to a heatmap of red to yellows?

2) How do I have alternative ylabs for my first and second plot? As my `ylab` function above just provides two y-axis names for each plot.

Comment: When you use a function like `fanchart` that is not part of base R,  you should include in your code the library statement to let us know which library to use, e.g. `library(vars)`. You should provide some sample data so that we can test out your code.   Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Apologies I was just looking for a quick description and did not think the data was required. I have updated this now, hopefully it is sufficiently detailed.